# How can I protect VUE component files from being viewed by unauthorized users?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm starting to study vue.js + laravel and there was a question that I can't find the answer to.

Let's say there is a component in the administrative part of the site for setting user rating coefficients. If someone sees at least a template of this component, they will be able to understand what the rating is based on and how it will be possible to influence this rating. I want to avoid it.

How can I prevent an unauthorized user from viewing my components from the administrative part through js bundles?

Comment: Well simply put, you can't hide the code once it's loaded in the browser. What you can do however is to have a specific bundle for your admin panel that you only load when needed

Comment: How can a bundle be loaded in such a way that its url is known only to an authorized user?

Comment: Because the backend loads it, when returning the html. You can also protect that file, for a example by using signed urls. You can even push things further with mTLS certificates to completely protect your admin panel but it might be overkill, and each admin will have to add the client certificate in their browser, not very pratical if there is a lot of users with admin access.

Comment: First of all, move any sensitive logic to backend. You can make admin url less predictable, but security through obscurity doesn't work. A proper way is to divide admin app into two bundled parts, auth and dashboard. The server should respond with 403 for any dashboard file without proper auth token

Comment: Estus Flask, could you write a simple example of the logic of working with two bundles? I can't figure out how to do this with vue+laravel((

Comment: @AndrewB Can you clarify? You need 2 admin vue apps, the first one is login form that receives auth token and saves it in a cookie and redirects to dashboard app. Can't help with the implementation laravel part, but you need to check auth cookie for all /dashboard/... requests and redirect back to /auth/ if it's invalid

Comment: Estus Flask, thanks! I will try.